# How to sovle error of ident auhentication in Ruby pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have setup rails app in local server.
success rake db:create and rake db:migrate.

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: passwd

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_test
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password: passwd

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_production
  pool: 5<
  username: user
  password: passwd
```

but cant connect in ruby pg

code

```
conn=PGconn.connect("localhost",5432,'','','db','user','passwd')
```

error

```
initialize': FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "user"(PG::ConnectionBad)
```

also modified pg_hba.conf, but the same error is displayed

`/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf`

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

User using in ruby and setup to create database is the same.

Problem is not found in the other
Please help me :(

> ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
>
> CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
>
> psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.1

Comment: you may post your database.yml as well?

Comment: did you try `rails c`

Comment: I was able to "rails c" and see the contents of the table.

Comment: funny. you have connected without an error when you are able to do `rails c` without an error :) There seems to be a misunderstanding. Do you get an error running `rails s` and connection to localhost:3000?

Comment: Now late, but I was able to connect　:)

Comment: check what `pg` service is run, do somethig like: `/etc/init.d/postgresql status`

Comment: In my environment is　"/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3 status"
 (pid  1274) running...